# Turing machine ( exponentiation )

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

How do I design Turing machine for exponential function $a^x$? I found this explanation http://philpapers.org/archive/LEMATM , but its too complicated. Could someone tell me please, is there another solution ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have to give the full details of the Turing machine (states, transition function, etc.), then it's certainly going to be complicated.